# Non conservative vector field

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

A question asked to show that $\vec{F}=\frac{-yi+xj}{x^2+y^2}$ is not conservative. My intuition was that $\vec{F}$ could be rewritten as $\frac{1}{x^2+y^2}(-yi+xj)$ and $-yi+xj$ is not a gradient nor conservative.

I know that you can choose a curve (unit circle) and show that is in fact not conservative, my question is whether my intuition is correct, ie. if a vector field can be rewritten as a scalar function (not identically 0) times a non conservative field would it always result in a non-conservative field.

Comment: Your intuition is not correct. That particular vector field, for example, is the result of $\nabla \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ (try it for yourself)

Comment: I learned that if $\vec{F}$ is a gradient it is conservative/path independant, in this case it's not conservative but apparently is a gradient of arctan. Where is the discrepancy?

Comment: is that scalar function defined everywhere?

Comment: I see, so because it is not defined at the origin the 'normal' rules do not apply. In this case it is a gradient but not conservative on a loop around the origin. That said if that scalar function was defined everywhere would the intuition apply? Conversely wouldn't it apply in this case as well if I were to says that since $-yi+xj$ is not conservative any non trivial scalar function times it would be non-conservative?